# Why trim() is removing first letter if it is in the url string php

Tags: php, trim

I want to strip the url and the trailing characters to extract just the id in the url. However, it is removing the first character of the id if it is in the trim string.

Example: https: //website.com/profile/**w300u-87wz**?utm_source=ab&utm_medium=email

I want to return w300u-87wz but it is returning 300u-87wz without the first "w".

If the id starts with any letter in the string "https: //website.com/profile/" it strips that letter at the beginning, only.

If it does not contain a letter in the string "https: //website.com/profile/" it works fine.

Example: https: //website.com/profile/**d300u-87wz**?utm_source=ab&utm_medium=email

It does return d300u-87wz

```
if($platformsearch == "category_website"){
    $str = $searchuser2;
    $str2 = ltrim($str, "https://www.website.com/profile/");
    $str3 = strtok($str2, '?');

    $searchuser2 = $str3;
}
```

I have tried ltrim() and trim().

How can I get it to strip the exact string and keep the rest?

**UPDATE...**
I can use str_replace() will do the trick and even further if viewed from an "about" email.

If link is retrieved directly or from about email section:

```
if($platformsearch == "category_website"){

$str = $searchuser2;
$str2 = str_replace("https://www.website.com/profile/", "", $str);
$str3 = str_replace("about/", "", $str2);
$str4 = strtok($str3, '?');
$searchuser2 = $str4;
```

}

Example: https: //website.com/profile/w300u-87wz?utm_source=ab&utm_medium=email

Will return "w300u-87wz"

It will then continue to run through if from about email to remove "about/"

Example: https: //website.com/profile/about/w300u-87wz?utm_source=ab&utm_medium=email

Will return "w300u-87wz"

**However, in seeing answer, below (marked as correct answer) using `parse_url()` is the cleanest and easiest option for stripping a url!**

Comment: The second parameter to `ltrim` is a list of characters to trim. So you're literally asking for `$str` to be stripped of any letters `h,t,p,s,:,/,w,.,e,b,i,c,o,m,p,r,f,l`.

Comment: @gingerCodeNinja but it only strips the first letter. it keeps the last w. how can I strip exact string and keep the rest? ty

Comment: If you simply want to remove `https://www.website.com/profile/` from the front of your string, `substr($str, strlen('https://www.website.com/profile/'));`, or as @RiggsFolly suggests, first parse the URL with `parse_url`, then use the path or querystring etc.

Comment: $url =  "https://website.com/profile/w300u-87wz?utm_source=ab&utm_medium=email";
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$parts = explode('/', $path);
$lastPart = end($parts);
// $lastPart is 'w300u-87wz'

Comment: @kristina it isn't simply stripping the first letter, it's stripping all those letters, it just so happens that the 'w' at the start of your string is the only character matching the list `h,t,p,s,:,/,w,.,e,b,i,c,o,m,p,r,f,l`, the 'd', 'u', 'z', '-' and numbers are not in that list.

Comment: @gingerCodeNinja There is indeed a second "w" before the "z". And the 2nd w is not stripped. Am I missing something completely? I am using your code in previous comment. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: @kristina sorry you are right, I should clarify - ltrim() will take as many characters off from the list of characters until it finds one character that is not in that list. In your case it hits the 'd' and stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mix of `parse_url()` and `explode()` and `end()` would be one way to skin this particular cat.

```
$s = 'https: //website.com/profile/w300u-87wz?utm_source=ab&utm_medium=email';

$a = parse_url($s);

$bits = explode('/', $a['path']); 
echo end($bits);
```

RESULT

```
w300u-87wz
```

Comment: Or use path functions for paths `echo basename(parse_url($s, PHP_URL_PATH));`